# converting to JSON: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/filter/TokenFilter

Tags: json, maven, elasticsearch, spring-boot, jackson

I frankly stack at problem with Elasticsearch (ES), which i cant figured out. I am new to ES and by following the tutorial from [this](https://dzone.com/articles/elasticsearch-java-api) site, the below error is occuring while running the project:

```
2016-12-31 00:23:38.877 ERROR 6120 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
```

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/filter/TokenFilter
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.json.JsonXContent.createGenerator(JsonXContent.java:73)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder.(XContentBuilder.java:112)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder.(XContentBuilder.java:102)

py pom.xml is:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
         </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
            <!-- JSOUP DEPENDENCY-->
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
         <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
         <version>4.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

and My working class is:

```
    Node node  = nodeBuilder().settings(Settings.builder().put("path.home","/data"))
                              .clusterName("elasticsearch").node();
    Client client = node.client();
    //SearchQuery searchQuery ;
    private static final String INDEX_NAME = "Proven_news";
    private static final String TYPE = "news";


    public void createIndex(ProvenNews pNews)
    {
        System.out.println(pNews.getId());
        client.prepareIndex(INDEX_NAME, TYPE, pNews.getId().toString()).setSource(putJsonDocument(pNews)).execute().actionGet();
        System.out.println(pNews.getUrl() + " - saved in ElasticSearch");
    }


    public static Map<String, Object> putJsonDocument(ProvenNews pNews)
    {
        Map<String, Object> jsonDocument = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        jsonDocument.put("entity", pNews.getEntity());
        jsonDocument.put("newsDate", pNews.getNewsDate());
        jsonDocument.put("newsText", pNews.getNewsText());
        jsonDocument.put("title", pNews.getTitle());
        jsonDocument.put("url", pNews.getUrl());
        return jsonDocument;
}
```

Today is 31 Dec, let the magic occur. Any constructive assist is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

where is the pom loading the jackson libraries....I think jackson-core jar is not added to your lib folder when you deploy....please list the maven entries for the jackson libraries.